# Windows phone keyboard open events and properties

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, keyboard-events

On my Windows Phone app I need to change my view accordingly to my keyboard. 
I have several questions:

How can I identify that the keyboard is opened? Is there an event on view for keyboard opening?

Is there a way to get the height of the keyboard? 
Or the  area size of the blocked UI (by keyboard)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access to keyboard information by `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane` class. There is static method `GetForCurrentView()`. It returns InputPane for current view. InputPane has events `Hiding` and `Showing` and property `OccludedRect` which returns region that input pane is covering.

```
InputPane inputPane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
inputPane.Showing += OnInputPaneShowing;
inputPane.Hiding += OnInputPaneHiding;

Rect coveredArea = inputPane.OccludedRect;
```